# ¿Cómo crear un servidor TCP para comunicarme desde pc a un dispositivo android?

Tags: java, android, c#, tcp

Me gustaría recibir un poco de información sobre como podria hacer esto, he visto varios tutoriales y paginas donde dicen como hacerlo pero no proporcionan información sobre que se debe tener en cuenta o como es que funciona, espero puedan ayudarme, lo que busco mas que nada es poder crear como un especie de chat donde el servidor(pc) pueda enviar mensajes al cliente(android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un pequeño Ejemplo de Xamarin.Android, para tener mas nocion sobre el tema te recomienda que investiges un poco sobre Socket.IO.

Creo que lo que necesitas esta en el siguiente video-Tutorial
[Observar Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4g1mUMrppU)

```
    using System;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Webkit;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;

    namespace Rastalovely
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Rastalovely", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            HybridWebViewClient hybridWebClient;
            WebView webView;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
                Button sendDataButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sendDataButton);

                hybridWebClient = new HybridWebViewClient (this);


                sendDataButton.Click += SendDataButton_Click;

                //  Socket.io in WebView
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(hybridWebClient);
                var template = new RazorView();
                var page = template.GenerateString();

                webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", page, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

            }

            void SendDataButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (webView != null)
                {
                    hybridWebClient.SendMessage2Server (webView, "I am an Android!.");
                }
            }

            private class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
            {
                Activity context;
                public HybridWebViewClient(Activity context)
                {
                    this.context = context;
                }
                public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, string url)
                {
                    var scheme = "hybrid:";

                    if (!url.StartsWith(scheme))
                        return false;
                    var resources = url.Substring(scheme.Length).Split('?');
                    var method = resources[0];
                    var parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(resources[1]);

                    switch (method)
                    {
                        case "Send2Server":
                            SendMessage2Server(webView, url);
                            break;
                        case "Notify2App":
                            Toast.MakeText(context, "Handle the link in c#\n" + url, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// Method to invoke a function in JS
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="webView">Current Webview.</param>
                /// <param name="args">Message to send.</param>
                public void SendMessage2Server(WebView webView, string args)
                {
                    string jsCode = string.Format("javascript: SendMessage2Server('{0}');", args);

                    webView.LoadUrl(jsCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si te ha sido de ayuda favor de colocarla como útil la respuesta.

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho, gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría para una aplicación de chat crear un websocket no un socket, ya que el websocket es más entendible, puedes hacerlo tanto en Java o C# según sea tu elección, desde Java (Android Studio) O C# (Xamarin) podrás conectarte al servidor, y te evitas la fatiga de estar consultando cada X tiempo si hay mensajes nuevos.

https://www.varvet.com/blog/using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/

Comment: Investigar un poco sobre eso, debo ver todas las formas posibles de crearlo, gracias por la respuesta.